# Find the exact value of the infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Find the exact value of the infinite series given by $$S = \frac{1}{(3^2+1)} + \frac{1}{(4^2+2)} + \frac{1}{(5^2+3)} +  ... $$

I found the notation of how it would be written with sigma notation:
$$\sum_{x=1}^∞ \frac{1}{(x+1)(x+4)}$$

I don't know how to get an exact value for the sum after that.

Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  YOu'll get more help if your questions are easy to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: 
$$\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+4)}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+4}\right).$$
Can you see how to compute the telescopic sum?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not too sure on what telescopic sums are.

Comment: @ShadyAF to see that, just write write down $\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+4}$, for the few first values of $n$, one row for each $n$, and sum

Comment: Hey, thanks! I got it!

Answer (score 0):

You can write your sum as
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n+\left(n+2\right)^2}
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{n+\left(n+2\right)^2}=\frac{1}{n^2+5n+4}
$$
Then you need to write
$$
\frac{1}{n^2+5n+4}=\frac{a}{n-\alpha_1}+\frac{b}{n-\alpha_2}
$$
with $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ being the two roots of $n^2+5n+4$.
Can you take it from there ?